# selecting items from a given session array and store it in other session array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have an array `session('products')`

```
array:9 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "store" => "store1"
      "product" => "1"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "store" => "store1"
      "product" => "11"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "store" => "store2"
      "product" => "5"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "store" => "store3"
      "product" => "6"
    ]
    4 => array:2 [▼
      "store" => "store5"
      "product" => "16"
    ]
    5 => array:2 [▼
      "store" => "store5"
      "product" => "18"
    ]
  ]
```

Now I have another array that is `session('stores')`

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "store1"
  1 => "store2"
  2 => "store3"
  3 => "store5"
]
```

What I am trying to do is creating an session array dynamically and get the values from `session('products')` that are matching that means.

Lets say I take first value from `session('stores')` i.e `0=>"store1"`

Now I will check the `session('products')` for any Array that has store name as `store1` to illustrate it output would be like this

### OUTPUT

```
session('store1')
    array:4 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "11"
    ]
session('store2')
    array:4 [▼
      0 => "5"
    ]
session('store3')
    array:4 [▼
      0 => "6"
    ]
session('store5')
    array:4 [▼
      0 => "16"
      1 => "18"
    ]
```

What I tried

```
$full_array = session('products');
$stores = session('stores');

for($i=0; $i<=count($stores); $i++)
{
  foreach($full_array as $arr)
  {
    //dd($stores[$i]);
    //dd($arr['store']);
    if($arr['store'] === $stores[$i])
    {
      session()->push($stores[$i], $arr['product']);
    }
  }
}
```

But it says `Undefined offset: 4`. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: count($stores) - 1 or change <= to < , reason: count() just counts the number of elements in your array, meaning 4, right now you are looping 5 times through your array.. 0 - 4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a laravel dev, but this should safely perform the task without creating any unnecessary variables nor calling `count()` on each outer loop iteration.

```
foreach(session('stores') as $i=>$store){
    foreach(session('products') as $subarray){
        if($subarray['store']===$store){
            session()->push($store,$subarray['product']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alen Please do a test run of my code.  If anything in my above code is incorrect, please leave me a comment that explains what's wrong.  I don't want to be sowing faulty code on SO.  If it achieves the desired result, please award it the green tick so future SO readers can quickly find the best answer.

Comment: @Alen Did this solve your issue?  If so, please award my answer the green tick to signify that this question is sufficiently resolved. (thanks for the upvote.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$full_array = session('products');
$stores = session('stores');

    for($i=0; $i<count($stores); $i++)
    {
      foreach($full_array as $arr)
      {
        //dd($stores[$i]);
        //dd($arr['store']);
        if($arr['store'] === $stores[$i])
        {
          session()->push($stores[$i], $arr['product']);
        }
      }
    }
```

You need to change `<= to <` so that its index will start from 0 and end before count of stores.